# Selecting words with the keyboard in Sublime Text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, selection

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 8.1. Could be ST2, I don't think this is relevant.

I'm aware we can add multiple cursors to select different portions of different lines. Also, if we're looking for the same instance of a word, then we can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select the next, and so on.

But what if I want to select two words or phrases in the same line? For example:
"Winners don't use drugs"
I'm navigating the caret with the arrow keys so I can select the word "Winners" by doing a hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>. At that point, if I want to add the word "drugs" to the selection, then I'd have to hold Ctrl and use the mouse over it.

Can it be done via keyboard? Splitting into lines is not the point since this is all 'inline'. Also, navigating with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> will cause the previous selection to be lost.

The idea here is to easily select two words or expressions to transpose, like:
"drugs don't use Winners".

Thanks!

Comment: The fastest way I can think of is unfortunately via mouse. Hold Ctrl, click somewhere around 'Winners' and 'drugs', press (and release) d, press t (assuming transpose is Ctrl+t). As you can see you are holding Ctrl until the end of combination, which is time saving.

Comment: Thanks T! What you did worked. Unfortunately it still needs the mouse, but that's a huge help.